# Pyomo - WARNING: NEOS is temporarily unavailable

Tags: pyomo, ipopt, neos-server

I am trying to solve a problem by submitting it to NEOS and using ipopt as a slover:

```
    solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('neos')
    results = solver_manager.solve(self.miqp_instance, opt='ipopt', load_solutions=True, tee=True)
    self.miqp_instance.solutions.store_to(results)
    results.write()
```

But I am getting this issue:

```
WARNING: NEOS is temporarily unavailable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/PPRule-MIQP/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    miqp.solve_problem()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/PPRule-MIQP/MIQP.py", line 406, in solve_problem
    results = solver_manager.solve(self.miqp_instance, opt='ipopt', load_solutions=True, tee=True)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/async_solver.py", line 28, in solve
    return self.execute(*args, **kwds)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/manager.py", line 107, in execute
    ah = self.queue(*args, **kwds)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyomo/opt/parallel/manager.py", line 122, in queue
    return self._perform_queue(ah, *args, **kwds)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyomo/neos/plugins/kestrel_plugin.py", line 131, in _perform_queue
    % (solver_name, str(sorted(self._solvers.keys()))))
pyomo.opt.parallel.manager.ActionManagerError: Solver 'ipopt' is not recognized by NEOS. Solver names recognized:
[]
```

I have already `ipopt` installed in my machine, but I doubt this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your question answers itself. At the top of the output:

```
WARNING: NEOS is temporarily unavailable.
```

NEOS is a service run out of UW-Madison, and servers sometimes go down.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I have noticed the warning message and I don't think it is simply because the server is actually down, as I have tried many times at seperate intervals; It seems to me it is may be related to a connectivty issue.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? That might be the root of issues as well. Can be hard to troubleshoot connectivity.

Comment: I am actually, and this is what I am suspecting. Do you think a special setting of my proxy would help?